# how to print last p tag element from php variable

Tags: php

This code is below,

Suppose,

```
$GROUPS = $row['groups'];
```

If I print **$GROUPS** variable , output will be

```
<p> Item1 </p>
<p> Item 2 </p>
<p> Item 3 </p>
<p> Item 4 </p>
<p> Item 5 </p>
<p> Item 6 </p>
<p> Item 7 </p>
```

How to print last p tag element from $GROUPS variable. *Here Output is **Item 7***.

OR If i want to print 4/5/6 th p tag element (dynamically) from $GROUPS variable.

How can i solve this problem in **PHP Code**?

Comment: simply count the no. of items from array & use it as key to print it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is a new line after each row, you can explode by new line

```
$groups = "<p> Item1 </p>
<p> Item 2 </p>
<p> Item 3 </p>
<p> Item 4 </p>
<p> Item 5 </p>
<p> Item 6 </p>
<p> Item 7 </p>";

$groups_arr = explode("\n",$groups);

echo "The last element:".$groups_arr[count($groups_arr)-1];
echo "\n";
echo "The 5th element:".$groups_arr[5-1];
```

with

`$groups_arr[count($groups_arr)-1];`

you can easily refer to the last element of your array regardless the arrays items count.

for the N element just refer to N-1 since the FIRST element is the 0.
example:

`echo "The 5th element:".$groups_arr[5-1];`

on action here:
http://3v4l.org/4j66Y

if you want to dynamically print from X to Y element of an array try this function

```
function PrintFromTo($start,$end,$array)
{
    if(!is_array($array))
        return false;

    $inc=0;
    foreach($array as $an_element)
    {
        $inc++;
        if(($inc>=$start)&&($inc<=$end))
        {
            echo $an_element; // tip: you can append a new line character or a <br>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string on the closing p tag, and then access the elements in the created array:

```
$groupsarray = explode('</p>',$GROUPS);

echo $groupsarray[6] . '</p>'; //add back closing p tag
```

Comment: Sure, only designed to work with his example code, and i cant say i have ever seen nested paragraph tags, though im sure its done.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

preg_match_all("#<p>(.*)</p>#", $GROUPS, $match);
print $match[0][6]; // Item 7

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTML parser like **[DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)** along with **[DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)** to efficiently break down the HTML into tags (for easier manipulation)

Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$p = $xpath->query('//p');
//getting last item:
$last =  $p->length - 1;
echo $p->item($last)->nodeValue;

//getting 3rd item:
echo $p->item(2)->nodeValue;
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/i5WF9hSA)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the way that `$row['groups'];` stores it's data - with `json_encode`.

For example, we have a string like; `<p>Item 1</p> ... <p>Item 7</p>`, we could store this in an array, like;

```
$arrGroups = array();

$arrGroups[] = "Item 1";
$arrGroups[] = "Item 2";
$arrGroups[] = "Item 3";
$arrGroups[] = "Item 4";
```

And then `json_encode` that array, and store it in `$row['groups']`.

Now that `$row['groups']` holds a json string representing an array `["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"]` - we can use this to our advantage by decoding it back into an array, and choosing the element we want.

```
$arrGroups = json_decode($row['groups'], true);
//Item 4
echo $arrGroups[count($arrGroups)-1]; //-1 because indexing starts at 0
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `explode` as suggested by other answers, it perhaps would be much more robust to generate the `<p>`s seperately and store them in an array, such as:

Instead of

```
$groups = "<p> Item1 </p>
<p> Item 2 </p>
<p> Item 3 </p>
<p> Item 4 </p>
<p> Item 5 </p>
<p> Item 6 </p>
<p> Item 7 </p>";

echo $groups;
```

use

```
$groups = array(
    " Item 1 ",
    " Item 2 ",
    " Item 3 ",
    " Item 4 ",
    " Item 5 ",
    " Item 6 ",
    " Item 7 ");

echo "<p>".implode("</p><p>", $groups)."</p>";
```

If you do so, you can easily access " Item 7 " with `$groups[6]`.